# Creating a stored procedure for a subscribed report

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I'm trying to create a notification system that alerts me when something is setup incorrectly in our ERP database. I have a report that I manually have to run every day to check on to see if there's anything for me to fix. Instead of doing that I'd like to have the report emailed to me or some sort of notification sent to me.

Someone suggested the following:

- Create the report in SSRS (Done; if the report doesn't have any data there's nothing to fix if there is data, I need to fix something)
- Create a stored procedure that will raise an error if there is no data
- The SSRS report will use the stored procedure dataset
- Subscribe to the report and it will only send an email if data exists

I'm stuck on the second part with the stored procedure, here's my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE JOBNOMATS
AS
SELECT CASE 
            WHEN (SELECT "JobHead"."JobNum", "JobHead"."Company", "JobHead"."PartDescription", "JobHead"."ReqDueDate", "JobMtl"."PartNum", "JobMtl"."MtlSeq", "JobHead"."InCopyList", "JobHead"."Plant"
            FROM   {oj "Epicor10Live"."Erp"."JobHead" "JobHead" LEFT OUTER JOIN "Epicor10Live"."Erp"."JobMtl" "JobMtl" ON ("JobHead"."Company"="JobMtl"."Company") AND ("JobHead"."JobNum"="JobMtl"."JobNum")}
            WHERE  "JobHead"."Company"='011' AND "JobMtl"."PartNum" IS  NULL  AND  NOT ("JobHead"."JobNum"='95057' OR "JobHead"."JobNum"='AISMNJOB')) IS NULL 
THEN RAISERROR(50001,16,1) 
 ELSE SELECT "JobHead"."JobNum", "JobHead"."Company", "JobHead"."PartDescription", "JobHead"."ReqDueDate", "JobMtl"."PartNum", "JobMtl"."MtlSeq", "JobHead"."InCopyList", "JobHead"."Plant"
            FROM   {oj "Epicor10Live"."Erp"."JobHead" "JobHead" LEFT OUTER JOIN "Epicor10Live"."Erp"."JobMtl" "JobMtl" ON ("JobHead"."Company"="JobMtl"."Company") AND ("JobHead"."JobNum"="JobMtl"."JobNum")}
            WHERE  "JobHead"."Company"='011' AND "JobMtl"."PartNum" IS  NULL  AND  NOT ("JobHead"."JobNum"='95057' OR "JobHead"."JobNum"='AISMNJOB')
```

But I get these two errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure JOBNOMATS, Line 7 Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'RAISERROR'.

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure JOBNOMATS, Line 9 Incorrect
>   syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.

Comment: For starters, your `SELECT CASE` requires and `END`

Comment: @RickS Thanks - should I add just one END or after each evaluation?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that in a CASE statement.
You can try something like this...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE JOBNOMATS
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT NULL
        FROM   {oj "Epicor10Live"."Erp"."JobHead" "JobHead" 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN "Epicor10Live"."Erp"."JobMtl" "JobMtl" ON 
                ("JobHead"."Company"="JobMtl"."Company") 
            AND ("JobHead"."JobNum"="JobMtl"."JobNum")}
        WHERE  "JobHead"."Company"='011' AND "JobMtl"."PartNum" IS NULL  
        AND  NOT ("JobHead"."JobNum"='95057' OR "JobHead"."JobNum"='AISMNJOB')
    )
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR(50001,16,1);
    END

    SELECT "JobHead"."JobNum", "JobHead"."Company", "JobHead"."PartDescription", "JobHead"."ReqDueDate", "JobMtl"."PartNum", "JobMtl"."MtlSeq", "JobHead"."InCopyList", "JobHead"."Plant"
    FROM   {oj "Epicor10Live"."Erp"."JobHead" "JobHead" LEFT OUTER JOIN "Epicor10Live"."Erp"."JobMtl" "JobMtl" ON ("JobHead"."Company"="JobMtl"."Company") AND ("JobHead"."JobNum"="JobMtl"."JobNum")}
    WHERE  "JobHead"."Company"='011' AND "JobMtl"."PartNum" IS  NULL  AND  NOT ("JobHead"."JobNum"='95057' OR "JobHead"."JobNum"='AISMNJOB')

END
```

There are better ways to do this.
Running the same query twice is a bit of a waste.

You can also check the @@ROWCOUNT after the query was executed, and raise the error if it was 0

```
CREATE PROCEDURE JOBNOMATS
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT "JobHead"."JobNum", "JobHead"."Company", "JobHead"."PartDescription", "JobHead"."ReqDueDate", "JobMtl"."PartNum", "JobMtl"."MtlSeq", "JobHead"."InCopyList", "JobHead"."Plant"
    FROM   {oj "Epicor10Live"."Erp"."JobHead" "JobHead" LEFT OUTER JOIN "Epicor10Live"."Erp"."JobMtl" "JobMtl" ON ("JobHead"."Company"="JobMtl"."Company") AND ("JobHead"."JobNum"="JobMtl"."JobNum")}
    WHERE  "JobHead"."Company"='011' AND "JobMtl"."PartNum" IS  NULL  AND  NOT ("JobHead"."JobNum"='95057' OR "JobHead"."JobNum"='AISMNJOB')

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
        RAISERROR(50001,16,1);

END
```

OR

You could also select the results into a temp table, and if the record count in the temp table is 0, raise the error... else select everything from the temp table...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE JOBNOMATS
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT "JobHead"."JobNum", "JobHead"."Company", "JobHead"."PartDescription", "JobHead"."ReqDueDate", "JobMtl"."PartNum", "JobMtl"."MtlSeq", "JobHead"."InCopyList", "JobHead"."Plant"
    INTO #TEMP
    FROM   {oj "Epicor10Live"."Erp"."JobHead" "JobHead" LEFT OUTER JOIN "Epicor10Live"."Erp"."JobMtl" "JobMtl" ON ("JobHead"."Company"="JobMtl"."Company") AND ("JobHead"."JobNum"="JobMtl"."JobNum")}
    WHERE  "JobHead"."Company"='011' AND "JobMtl"."PartNum" IS  NULL  AND  NOT ("JobHead"."JobNum"='95057' OR "JobHead"."JobNum"='AISMNJOB')

    IF (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM #TEMP) = 0
        RAISERROR(50001,16,1);

    --DO MORE STUFF IF YOU WANT TO...

    SELECT *
    FROM #TEMP
END
```

all depends how expensive the query is

Comment: Thanks a lot! The last one seems like it's the most efficient.

Comment: I would go with the second one... checking @@ROWCOUNT. But it's your call.

Comment: Alright, you obviously know much more than I do about this. Second one it is!